# Return value after Try statement

Tags: return, try-catch

Only recently started doing code so be gentle and have been given a a very simple assignment from my college.

```
private static double getNumber()

{
double value1;


Console.WriteLine("please enter your first number");

try

{
value1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

return value1;

}

catch

{
Console.WriteLine("Must be numeric");

}
```

I've tried putting the return value1 all over the place however i keep getting the error message Program.getNumber()': not all code paths return a value.

Thoughts?

Comment: If your parse fails then your return wont get hit. It skips over it and hits the catch block. You need to put a return statement in your catch block as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should have return statement in you catch block as well.

Comment: Which means value1 has to be initialized to something . . .

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets - inside a method, you need to definitely assign a value.

Answer (score 1):

Just put return outside the block:

```
 private static double getNumber()    
 {
    double value1 = 0;  
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your first number");
    try    
    {
       value1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());   
    }
    catch
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("Must be numeric");
    }
    return value1;
 }
```

It will occure whenever try passed or caught.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static double getNumber()
{ 
    double value1=0;    
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your first number");

    try    
    { 
        value1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Must be numeric");
    }
    return value1;
}
```